# Looking for an option to only keep recent data in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a chunk of data that I am fetching from API every x minutes and uploading it to a collection in mongodb.

The data I am fetching might change between each calls. As I need to store only the updated data to the DB, I am deleting all the documents in the collection and then adding all the data again fetched from the api.

This process doesn’t seem to be a good one. So I was wondering if there any other way where I can keep my DB updated with all the latest data fetching from api every x minutes.

Comment: you can always update the one record on the database so you don't have to delete and insert a record, providing sample code would be better for understating the question

Comment: @KakSarkar updation won't work, and let me. tell you why. Let's say on the first call to the api, I get 10 data and store it to the DB. Now may be on the second call, I will get 8 data which can be same as old or different. So if different, then updation will keep old data in the DB which I don't need.